# Alternative to ffmpeg for iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ffmpeg, video-processing

I've been trying to implement ffmpeg in my ios app several weeks. And now I can play several avi files, but other files like a flv, wma, mp4... play slow.

I have spent much time with ffmpeg and opengl and I don't find solution.

I'm looking other alternatives to play this files on ios device.

Someone know other libraries, frameworks, ... that I can use to play this files. No matter if they have business licenses.

Very thanks,

Edited:

Init Shader:

```
 shader = [[GLShader alloc] initWithFileName:@"render" attributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"position",
                                                                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:1], @"texCoords", nil]
                                         uniforms:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"sampler0",
                                                                                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], @"viewProjectionMatrix",nil]];
```

render.fsv:

```
uniform sampler2D sampler0;
varying highp vec2 _texcoord;
void main()
{ gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler0, _texcoord);}
```

render.vsf:

```
attribute vec4 position;
attribute vec2 texCoords;
varying  vec4 colorVarying;
varying vec2 _texcoord;
uniform mat4 viewProjectionMatrix;

void main()
{   _texcoord = texCoords;   
gl_Position = viewProjectionMatrix * position;}
```

How I can implement your solution in this code?

Comment: Be careful - _9.1 Apps that do not use the MediaPlayer framework to access media in the Music Library will be rejected_

Comment: Well, if it's an AVI or WMA, doubtful it's in the Music Library...

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced similar problems. There were two bottlenecks:

1. decoding
2. conversion from yuv to rgb formats

I solved the second problem by converting image using shaders. It works really fast now (I can render 6 videos simulteneously at 30 fps on iPad2).

Here is part of the fragment shader:

```
    uniform sampler2D y;
    uniform sampler2D u;
    uniform sampler2D v;

    ...
    y = texture2D(y, vec2(nx,ny)).r;
    u = texture2D(u, vec2(nx, ny)).r - 0.5;
    v = texture2D(v, vec2(nx, ny)).r - 0.5;

    r = y + 1.13983*v;
    g = y - 0.39465*u - 0.58060*v;
    b = y + 2.03211*u;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(r, g, b, 1.0);
```

NOTE: you have to store y,u,v components in 3 different textures.

nx and ny - are normalized texture coordinates (from 0 to 1 texture ).

Comment: Hi max very thanks for your answer. I'm really very happy for your answer. I' don't have much idea of opengl and shaders. 

Do you know of any example?

Comment: It's really not too complicated. You just need to use samplers to get pixel color and then convert it using simple equation of you-rgb conversion. You can find it on Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Conversion_to.2Ffrom_RGB

Comment: Hi max, I don't know where I can add this code. In my render method I get the frame buffer in uint8_t format. I edit the post with this method. Very thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi max, I know where you include code, but not how to do it correctly. I edited the post with my fragment shader code. Thanks,

Comment: Hi max, I need to resolve this as soon as possible. I can not contact with you. I would like to collaborate with me. If you want, please contact with me. ggdiez@gmail.com.

Comment: So what exactly you don't understand?

Comment: How I can divide my yuv frame in 3 textures? I need this to store y,u,v components in 3 different textures. My yuv frame is a uint8_t pointer.

Comment: AVPicture has got data member which has several color channels. Just create several textures using my_frame->data[i]

Comment: Sorry Max, I'm very new with openGL ES. I try to understand it to finish this project. I think I can get the textures of my buffer, but I don't know exactly how to do. My buffer is uint8_t *buffer. Y=buffer[1]; U=buffer[2]; V=buffer[3], Could it be?

Comment: rendering 6 video simultaneously at 30fps is quite impressive, how did you accelerate the decoding?